# Using both @RequestMapping and @ModelAttribute on a method

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use both `@RequestMapping` and `@ModelAttribute` annotations on the same method in a Spring MVC Controller?

For example I'd like to obtain something like:

```
@ModelAttribute("export_profiles")
@RequestMapping(value = "/profiles_list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
ExportProfile[] getExportProfilesList() {
    edService.getProfiles();
}
```

I'd like to use this approach because, in my page I have to load a list of `ExportProfile`s as `option`s into a `select`. In the same page I can create/delete export profiles, so I have to refresh the profiles list in my select, and I'd like to do this asynchronously using an ajax call to the same metod.

Is it possible to use a single method to set a model attribute and to handle asynchronous requests? Or do I have to use two different methods?

Comment: its not clear, to me at least, what you require. I normally just inject model into method and use model.getAttribute

Comment: @NimChimpsky What I want to do is to set an `ExportProfile` array as model attribute, to populate a `select` the first time I load the page. Then when a profile is created/deleted I want to reload the profiles asynchronously, so I have to call another method in the controller. So ultimately I want to know If there is a way to use only one method to do both things.

Comment: @Luciano I tried the piece of code in my question and doesn't work, but I wonder if there's a way to fix it...

Comment: According to me both the annotations will not work on top of same method. You have to make two separate methods in order to achieve this.

Comment: What is it that it's not working? ModelAttribute and RequestMapping should work together. But I think that ModelAttribute and ResponseBody are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is to set an ExportProfile array as model attribute,
>   to populate a select the first time I load the page

you can just set an attribute of a page like so ...

```
public String myMethodThatInitiatesPage(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("exportProfiles", edService.getProfiles())
return "yrViewName";
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's definitely the simplest way. Thank you.